# Accidently deleted XCDataModel - Application now throws NSInvalidArgumentException - iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

I accidentally deleted my core data model file, I then tried to re-add it, but now my application throws the following:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Cannot create an NSPersistentStoreCoordinator with a nil model'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1ef6022 0x186ecd6 0x1593a75 0x3021 0x2cea 0x34b0 0x26e5 0x6f0386 0x6f1274 0x700183 0x700c38 0x6f4634 0x2089ef5 0x1eca195 0x1e2eff2 0x1e2d8da 0x1e2cd84 0x1e2cc9b 0x6f0c65 0x6f2626 0x22ed 0x2255)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)
```

Can anyone explain the steps I need to take to get my app working again?

Cheers,

Tysin

Comment: Use your version control system to rollback before you deleted it. Failing that, make sure it's added to the target.

Comment: aren't you using a git? then you could restore it easily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though obviously one should be using some form of source control, this was a small project so I didn't create a repository.  For those in the same boat the following solved my problem:

In the method:

```
// Returns the managed object model for the application.
// If the model doesn't already exist, it is created from the application's model.
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{
    if (_managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return _managedObjectModel;
    }
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"AppName" withExtension:@"momd"];
    _managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    return _managedObjectModel;
}
```

I changed the line:

```
NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"AppName" withExtension:@"momd"];
```

to:

```
NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"AppName" withExtension:@"momd"];
```

I just removed the 'd' from the model file extension and everything worked.